# Classes decorated with @freezed cannot have mutable properties

Tags: flutter, dart

Running build runner on the following code outputs an error

```
@freezed
abstract class Person implements _$Person {
  const Person._(); // Added constructor
  int _readCount = 0;
  factory Person({ String name, int age }) = _Person;
  getPrivatVar(){ return _readCount++ }
}
```

Classes decorated with @freezed cannot have mutable properties

But _readCount is a **private** proprety. Why does it also check private proprety. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

[Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#basics) says about itself:

> Code generation for **immutable** classes that has a simple syntax/API without compromising on the features.

Emphasis is mine. Immutable classes. Your class is not immutable, it has state. It doesn't matter whether your state is public or private, it's still mutable.

You can fix it by removing the private state from your class.

Comment: But, you can use the `copyWith` function to make a new copy with the changed public properties.